# Filtering on MS SSRS 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2, cube

Can anybody please give me a idea how to filter this out? When Somebody buy something, they can add optional warranty to their product. I need to create a report when they attached that warranty, I need to see the product too.  I don't need to see any other sales. Warranty for that product should be under same invoice number. Please see below picture.

[image]

I have two types of warranty. I try to filter it out using "Contain, IN"  by giving warranty name and SKU doesn’t not work. When I do that it only gives me warranty name on the invoice. Please see below picture for the result.

[image]

How do I get the product name also when they attached the warranty too.(I have two type of warranty too, For a example  X and Y. When some body attached X or Y for product, I need to see the product and warranty type only). I would really appreciate if anybody could tell me how to get that.

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you post your SQL in text format?

Comment: @TonyD

I don't use query on my MS SSRS 3.0. I just used query designer to build my report, but please see below query that I generated from query designer.

Its too long, so  I attached a link for query, 

Query - [link] (https://docs.google.com/document/d/19eH4jHZYl0GtEWPAR2mJOcGmj_OVooWDJPK4JrS78hg/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you so

Comment: Design mode image - [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6dDEzMcQGJremFwak9Cdm9DRThWYkRUcldvQmhObGJpTnln)

Comment: Is there any way you can copy the query text?

Comment: @TonyD,
 Its too long, but I copied to this google doc. You can see it on this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19eH4jHZYl0GtEWPAR2mJOcGmj_OVooWDJPK4JrS78hg/edit) 
Thank you.

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Comment: I'd update your tags to include "MDX".  That's what it looks like.  Sorry, unable to help.

Comment: @TonyD, Well, I am connected to the vendor's  SQL server analysis service. I used MS SQL Server Reporting Services to create the report. That is why I stuck and pretty hard to query on this. Thank you

Comment: Try this article https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/09c22944-5f0c-4db1-9a5a-d0799f6a5e48/filter-dimension-value-using-mdx-in-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @TonyD
Sir, I really appreciate your help and time. I will look into that. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: No worries, mate. I wish I knew MDX a bit better.

Comment: Please add the mdx it is not very long

Comment: @whytheq

I already added the code on top link. I am not sure how make it short. Please it [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19eH4jHZYl0GtEWPAR2mJOcGmj_OVooWDJPK4JrS78hg/edit) . I tired to past here from Select statement, still too long. Thank you